# How would I query two custom cells in one UITableViewController in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2

I want to be able to see two different cells in one tableview. This not being separated into sections. So would you make it one section or what?

Comment: Can you actually show what you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that with for example:

```
switch indexPath.row {
case 0:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FirstTableViewCell
case 1:

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SecondTableViewCell
default:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell3", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ThirdTableViewCell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewCell`s need an identifier that you can use to refer to them individually.

A `UITableView` can have multiple default cells with different identifiers.

On Interface Builder, select your `UITableView` and then on Attributes Inspector change the `Prototype Cells` value to match your needs.

[image]

Then, select the cell and assign it a unique identifier.

[image]

If you're using code to create your `UITableView`, you have to register a `UITableViewCell` subclass for each unique identifier:

```
tableView.registerClass(MyTableViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
tableView.registerClass(AnotherTableViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
```

Regardless of how you registered your cells, you then can decide which prototype cell to use on `UITableView`s delegate method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```